# Use imported modules within factory using Object.assign (closure)

Tags: javascript

I have a factory function as follows:

```
import moduleA from'./modulea'
import moduleB from'./moduleb'
import { componentA, componentB } from './components'

module.exports = () => {
    //DECLARE VARIABLES SHARED BY FUNCTIONS
    const util = moduleA.util() //RETURNS OBJECT

    return Object.assign({}, {
        componentA,
        componentB
    }
}
```

Originally, componentA and componentB were functions within the factory function and any imported modules or variables in the declared variables section were available within each component.

```
import moduleA from'./modulea'
import moduleB from'./moduleb'

module.exports = () => {
    //DECLARE VARIABLES SHARED BY FUNCTIONS
    const util = moduleA.util() //RETURNS OBJECT

    const componentA = () => {
        //MODULES AVAILABLE
        //DECLARED VARIABLES AVAILABLE
        //DO STUFF
    }

    const componentA = () => {
        //MODULES AVAILABLE
        //DECLARED VARIABLES AVAILABLE
        //DO STUFF
    }

    return Object.assign({}, {
        componentA,
        componentB
    }
}
```

Since moving the functions to `'./components'`, as individual files for each function, the imported modules and declared variables are now no longer available to the components, even with using Object.assign. I've tried passing them into Object.assign to no avail.

Is there a way to have the imported modules and declared variables available to my imported components so that I can break up the factory into smaller components in separate files without having to import them in each component file? I'm trying to do this with closure.

Comment: Why are you mixing ES6 and Commonjs syntax? Don't do that.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You really *should* import the utils in each component file that needs them. That's how declaring dependencies works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components module should also import whatever modules it needs.

```
// "components" module

// Just like any other module, import what you need
import moduleA from'./modulea'
import moduleB from'./moduleb'

const util = moduleA.util()

export const componentA = () => {
    //MODULES AVAILABLE
    //DECLARED VARIABLES AVAILABLE
    //DO STUFF
}

export const componentA = () => {
    //MODULES AVAILABLE
    //DECLARED VARIABLES AVAILABLE
    //DO STUFF
}
```

---

EDIT (in response to comment):

I don't necessarily recommend either of these other options, but here's a couple other things you could do:

1) Attach everything to "this".

```
// "components" module

// Component functions are non-arrow functions so you can use "this"
export function componentA() {
    this.moduleA
    this.moduleB
    this.util
}

export function componentA() {
    this.moduleA
    this.moduleB
    this.util
}
```

Then in your main module:

```
module.exports = () => {
    //DECLARE VARIABLES SHARED BY FUNCTIONS
    const util = moduleA.util() //RETURNS OBJECT

    return Object.assign({}, {
        componentA,
        componentB,

        // other properties the component functions expect to have
        moduleA,
        moduleB,
        util
    }
}
```

Or 2) pass everything as arguments:

```
// "components" module

export const componentA = (moduleA, moduleB, util) => {
    //MODULES AVAILABLE
    //DECLARED VARIABLES AVAILABLE
    //DO STUFF
}

export const componentA = (moduleA, moduleB, util) => {
    //MODULES AVAILABLE
    //DECLARED VARIABLES AVAILABLE
    //DO STUFF
}
```

Then in your main module:

```
module.exports = () => {
    //DECLARE VARIABLES SHARED BY FUNCTIONS
    const util = moduleA.util() //RETURNS OBJECT

    return Object.assign({}, {
        componentA: (...args) => componentA(moduleA, moduleB, util, ...args),
        componentB: (...args) => componentB(moduleA, moduleB, util, ...args),
    }
}
```

---

P.S.

> each function in components has it's own file ... the functions that are now methods on that new object

It's weird that you're defining methods in separate files. You may have a deeper design problem here.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid having to do that since each function in components has it's own file. I was hoping there was some way to bind them to the new object so that they would be available to the functions that are now methods on that new object. I'm doing this for DI/IoC purposes.

Comment: @Kainan If you want to inject dependencies, have the modules export functions and pass them the dependencies as arguments.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm trying something like that right now. I'm making each component that returns an object with the function as a method and the modules exports brings in the dependency.

Comment: @Kainan I edited my answer to respond to your comment.